# Angularjs calendar Cannot call method 'fullCalendar' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

I have a calendar declared as follow

`<div class="calendar" ng-model="eventSources" id="eventCalendar" 
                        calendar="calendar" config="uiConfig.calendar"
                        ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar"></div>`

And in my Controller I have `$scope.eventSources = [$scope.monthEvent];`

When I try to get the start/end visibile date form the calendar I realize that it is not visible in my scope.
I tried to get it in two manners and both of them fail

- first one : `var endDay1 = $scope.calendar.fullCalendar('getView').end;`
- the second one : `var view = $('#eventCalendar').fullCalendar('getView');`

Should I inject particular things in order to see the calendar in the scope.

Thank you very much

Comment: according documentation you need to use `$scope.calendarName` in your controller, where calendarName is value of calendar attribute in DOM element which is associated with calendar. It seems that your first case should work. But it don't. I have the same issue and still not resolved it.

Answer (score 3):

The same problem gave me headaches for a couple of days and I just couldn't figure it out.
The only way to reach the fullcalendar object was through simple but ugly:

```
angular.element('#myCalendarId').fullCalendar('getViewOrWhatever');
```

Comment: This is a really helpful answer, I've been looking for a few days now and this is the only way I've been able to access the fullCalendar method. The documentation is very incomplete, especially if you're trying implement this calendar in angular

Answer (score 2):

yes you need to add dependency
add the following scripts

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="components/jquery-ui\ui\jquery-ui.custom.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular/angular.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular-ui-calendar/calendar.js"></script>
```

Add the calendar module as a dependency to your application module:

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.calendar'])
```

Apply the directive to your div elements:

```
<div ui-calendar>
```

The whole detail can be found [Here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar)